# How do I build a static library in WAF?

Tags: c++, waf

My scenario goes like this:

wscript:

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')        

def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load('compiler_c')
    ctx.load('compiler_cxx')        

def build(ctx):
    ctx.objects(source = "file0.c",
                target = "cFiles")

    ctx.objects(source = "file1.cpp file2.cpp",
                target = "cxxFiles")

    ctx.stlib(source = "???",
              target = "test")
```

How do I call 'ctx.stlib()'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ctx(features='c cxx cxxstlib', use='cFiles cxxFiles', target='test')

EDIT: removed dead link.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead